# How can I show an emergent window every hour?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, timer, repeat

Using `tkinter`, I'm doing an emergent window to remind me to drink water. At this point it works but now I want the section of `def trinke_wasser` to repeat every hour. I tried with the `time` module but in the end, I didn´t know where to write it.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

fenstern = Tk()
fenstern.title("Warnung")
fenstern.geometry("900x600")
datei = Image.open('wasser_pic.png')
bild = ImageTk.PhotoImage(datei)
img = Label(fenstern, image = bild)
img.place(x=0, y=0)

def choice(option):

    pop.destroy()


def trinke_wasser():

    global pop
    fenstern.wm_state('iconic')

    pop = Toplevel(fenstern)
    pop.title('popup')
    pop.geometry("900x600")
    back= Label(pop, image = bild)
    back.place(x=0, y=0)

    rhamen = Frame(pop, bg = "white")
    rhamen.pack(pady = 5)

    yes = Button(rhamen, text = "YES", command = lambda: choice ("yes"), bg = "orange")
    yes.grid(row=0, column=1)

die_Taste = Button(fenstern, text = "Beginnen", command = trinke_wasser )
die_Taste.pack(pady=100)

fenstern.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a scheduler application, like `cron` job in Linux, to execute your script every hour?

Answer (score 0):

With the time library, there is a sleep function which waits for a number of specified seconds. So if we calculate the number of seconds in an hour or 3600. We can call the sleep function which will wait for exactly 1 hour.

```
import time

time.sleep(3600)
```

So if you put the sleep function at the end of your trinke_wasser function. It will tell you to drink water, wait an hour and do it again, over and over

Comment: but it doesn't show the window again, it just give a delay of (e.g. ```time.sleep(5)```) 5 seconds before showing the window by first time.

Comment: did you put the function in a while True loop?

Answer (score 0):

In your current program, you just execute the `trinke_wasser()` function once upon pressing a key. What you want to do is to open a scheduler function that calls the function once every hour.
But you will have to allow this function to be terminated for good. So, you need a global boolean variable that may be turned off to end the loop. (you could also just end the program execution by force, but that's not nice)

So, what you want to do is to import the time library by adding `import time` at the beginning of the script.
After `fenstern` is defined, just add an attribute to this window that is `True` as long as you don't make it false: `fenstern.running = True`

Then, you can make your scheduler function:

```
def nerv_mich(delay = 3600):
    while fenstern.running:
        trinke_wasser()
        time.sleep(3600)
```

This function will run forever and ask you to drink water ever 3600 seconds.

You just have to adjust the command of the first button:

```
die_Taste = Button(fenstern, text = "Beginnen", command = nerv_mich)
```

Now, you just have to turn it off by using a second button just after the definition of `yes`

```
fertig = Button(rhamen, text = "Fertig jetzt!", command = lambda: choice ("fertig"), bg = "orange")
    yes.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Finally, you have to change the function `choice()` to really end the whole thing after the option passed to it is `"fertig"`:

```
def choice(option):
    pop.destroy()
    if option=="fertig": fenstern.running=False
```

That should work. You can also use `fentstern.destroy()` to completely end your program at this point. To be honest, you probably don't really need this initial window.